# Recursive Iteration in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like that:

```
 +----+-----+------+
 | id | ord | test |
 +----+-----+------+
 |  1 |   1 | A    |
 |  1 |   2 | B    |
 |  1 |   3 | C    |
 |  2 |   1 | B    |
 |  2 |   2 | C    |
 +----+-----+------+
```

(Here is some code for creating the data)

```
drop table temp_test;
create table temp_test (id varchar(20), ord varchar(20), test varchar(20));
insert into temp_test (id,ord,test) values ('1','1','A');
insert into temp_test (id,ord,test) values ('1','2','B');
insert into temp_test (id,ord,test) values ('1','3','C');
insert into temp_test (id,ord,test) values ('2','1','B');
insert into temp_test (id,ord,test) values ('2','2','C');
commit;
```

How could I get the following result?

```
+----+-----+-------+
| id | ord | test  |
+----+-----+-------+
|  1 |   1 | A     |
|  1 |   2 | A_B   |
|  1 |   3 | A_B_C |
|  2 |   1 | B     |
|  2 |   2 | B_C   |
+----+-----+-------+
```

I have tried using LAG(), something like:

```
  select CONCAT(lag(TEST) over (partition by ID order by ord),TEST) AS TEST from temp_test;
```

but it does not work recursively.

This code works:

```
SELECT 
R1.*,
(   SELECT  LISTAGG(test, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ord)
    FROM    temp_test R2
    WHERE   R1.ord >= R2.ord
    AND     R1.ID = R2.ID
    GROUP BY ID
) AS WTR_KEYWORD_1
FROM temp_test R1
ORDER BY id, ord;
```

but it is not performant enough for a larger data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some say the [Hierarchical queries](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html#GUID-0118DF1D-B9A9-41EB-8556-C6E7D6A5A84E) are outdated,  but they generally perform far better than recursive CTE

```
SELECT id,
       ord,
       LTRIM(sys_connect_by_path(test,'_'),'_') as test
FROM temp_test r2 START WITH ord = 1 -- use MIN() to get this if it's not always 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = id AND ord = PRIOR ord + 1;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3a5c16b52f62451d2e64f82549c42982)

Comment: Thanks, that is the fastest answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of recursive cte to achieve this

```
with cte(id,ord,test,concat_val) 
  as (select id,ord,test,test as concat_val
       from temp_test
       where ord=1
      union all
      select a.id,a.ord,a.test,b.concat_val||'_'||a.test
        from temp_test a
        join cte b
          on a.id=b.id
         and a.ord=b.ord+1 
      )
select * from cte order by id,ord
```

Demo here

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78baa20f7f364e653899caf63ce7ada2

Comment: That provides the correct result. I will check the performance. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The result is correct, but the accepted answer is about 100x faster on my data.